# How to raise click event on angular material radio button?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to trigger click event by key press, I have this simple component:

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected" aria-label="Select an option">
  <mat-radio-button #first value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

I want to raise click event:

```
this.matRadioButton._elementRef.nativeElement.click();
```

but it doesn't work.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eagy2a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Instead of calling the event on `_elementRef` you could call it on `_inputElement` property. And instead of directly calling the `click` event, you could use [`dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) function to trigger the event.

Try the following

```js
export class RadioOverviewExample {
  selected: string;
  @ViewChild('first', {static: false}) matRadioButton : MatRadioButton;

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() =>{
      let event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
      this.matRadioButton._inputElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eagy2a-djzz3y?file=src/app/radio-overview-example.ts).

#### Update: trigger event listeners

Since we are triggering the event on `this.matRadioButton._inputElement`, we could use RxJS `fromEvent` function to bind to the same element's click event.

Try the following

```js
import { Subject, Observable, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

...
export class RadioOverviewExample implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  selected: string;
  clickCount: number = 0;             // <-- use to close open subscriptions
  complete$ = new Subject<any>();

  @ViewChild('first', {static: false}) matRadioButton : MatRadioButton;
  
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
      this.matRadioButton._inputElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
    }, 1000);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.matRadioButton._inputElement.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
      takeUntil(this.complete$)
    ).subscribe(
      res => { this.clickCount++ }    // <-- click event handler
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.complete$.next();            // <-- close open subscriptions
  }
}
```

RxJS `takeUntil` operator is used to close any open subscriptions in the `ngOnDestroy()` hook to avoid potential memory leaks.

I've updated your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eagy2a-erlqj5?file=src/app/radio-overview-example.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. do you have any idea how to cause to radio button to raise here click event? as you can see the click count in you example is 0: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eagy2a-8jnlzn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-overview-example.html

Comment: You could use RxJS `fromEvent` function to bind to the `click` event. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This is easier when there are many observables to handle. You could just do `.pipe(takeUntil(this.complete$))` to each of the observable and in `ngOnDestroy()` only one statement is enough: `this.complete$.next()`. With `unsubscribe()` each subscription needs to be saved in a variable and unsubscribed individually.